# current action name problem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

When i am in /edit action, i see edit button but the problem is if there is an error in form validation it renders action edit and i see create button. how can i fix it?

```
<%= form_for(@page) do |f| %>
<% if controller.action_name =="edit" %>
<%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% else %>
<%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<% if ["edit", "update"].include? params[:action] %>
  <%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% else %>
  <%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

Better solution is to extract your form as a partial and send local variable with button name to it

your `edit` view:

```
<%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :button_label => "Edit" } %>
```

your `create` view:

```
<%= render :partial => "form", :locals => { :button_label => "create" } %>
```

your `_form` partial:

```
<%= form_for @object ... do |f| %>
  ...
  <%= f.submit button_label %>
<% end %>
```

**UPD**

I think @idlefingers solution the best for your issue

Answer (score 5):

You could just use `f.submit` with no arguments. This will create names like "Update Page" and "Create Page". If you want to change the wording of these, they can be set in your locale. No conditionals, no messing about with action names. Simple.

Answer (score 2):

Try to do this check:

```
<%= form_for(@page) do |f| %>
<% if controller.action_name =~ /update|edit/  %>
<%= f.submit "Update" %>
<% else %>
<%= f.submit "Create" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
<%= form_for(@page) do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit(f.object.new_record? ? "Create" : "Update") -%>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This will not work. When creating a new record, and a validation fails, `new_record?` will still be true.

Comment: And whats wrong ? If creating of new record is failed, this record is new, and button label should be  "Create".